# Media query not working - a simple demo page

Tags: html, responsive-design, media-queries, liquid-layout

Well, in a simple html page, I am not able to run media queries. I am working on these after a gap, hence I think i am making some stupid mistake, which i am unable to figure out.

jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/7DEpH/

HTML

```
<div class="resume">
    <section>
        <h2>Info</h2>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a dignissim ipsum. Aliquam venenatis sapien semper, rhoncus nulla nec, feugiat ligula. </p>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a dignissim ipsum. Aliquam venenatis sapien semper, rhoncus nulla nec, feugiat ligula. </p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.resume {width:50%;}
div.content {padding:10px 10px 25px;}
div.content p {text-align:justify; line-height:1.2em; font-size:.9em;}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {div.resume{width:100%}  }

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) { div.resume{width:100%}  }

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) { div.resume{width:100%}  }
```

This is just some sample code out from my page, which doesn't seem to work. I tried looking for similar questions here and on internet, but it looks like i already have those in place like, my page has right meta tag as below and am using HTML5 doctype

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

The media queries are not kicking in. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to use the tag "div" before your class and Maybe you are resizing the browser for test purpose and this will not work, if you want to have a more dynamic effect, you should be use min-width and max-width instead min-device-width and max-devide-width, please note the "device" word it not work because "device" gets the minimum width of the screen and not of the browser

```
.resume {width:50%;}
.content {padding:10px 10px 25px;}
.content p {text-align:justify; line-height:1.2em; font-size:.9em;}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px) {.resume{width:100%}  }

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) { .resume{width:100%}  }

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) { .resume{width:100%}  }
```

Comment: right, that's correct, it just came in mistakenly here, otherwise it had some other purpose in the large of code i have. Anyway, it doesnt seem to solve the problem though.

Comment: Maybe you are resizing the browser for test purpose and this will not work, if you want to have a more dynamic effect, you should be use min-width and max-width instead min-device-width and max-devide-width, please note the "device" word it not work because "device" gets the minimum width of the screen and not of the browser

Comment: Bingo!! it worked perfectly after removing the device and i understood why that's so, probably for my local testing, i need to do away with device. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: Cool! Please @whyAto8 mark as "answer useful", I'm happy that answer has been found useful for you, greetings